# Kotlin: CountDownTimer onTick interrupted by onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

In my multiple choice quiz app, an answer must be chosen and submitted before a CountDownTimer reaches 0. If the timer reaches 0 or the submitted answer is incorrect, a dialogBox is shown.

Here's my problem: If the user hits the 'Submit' button without selecting an answer, the timer resets and the text view quickly alternates between the reset time and the correct time. For example, if the timer is set for 20 seconds and 'Submit' is clicked when the timer shows 17 seconds, the timer displays the following: 20, 19, 18, 17, 19/16, 18/15, 17/14 and so on.
This issue is compounded each time the 'Submit' button is clicked.

How can I allow the timer to continue to run if 'Submit' is clicked without an answer selected?

Timer declaration

```
 private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer
 var isRunning: Boolean = true
```

Set question

```
private fun setQuestion() {
        val question = mQuestionsList!![mCurrentPosition - 1]
        defaultOptionsView()
        if(mCurrentPosition == mQuestionsList!!.size + 1){
            timer.cancel()
            btn_submit.text = "FINISH"
        }else{
            btn_submit.text = "SUBMIT"
        }
```

Timer

```
timer = object: CountDownTimer(20000, 1000){
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                val timeResult =
                    "${(millisUntilFinished/1000 / 60).toString().padStart(1, '0')}:" +
                    "${(millisUntilFinished/1000 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}"
                tv_timer.text = "$timeResult"
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                isRunning = false
                btn_submit.callOnClick()
                timer.cancel()
    //cancel the timer and simulate button click to treat answer as incorrect and show dialogBox
            }
        }.start()
```

OnClick

```
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            when(v?.id){
                R.id.radio_button1 -> {
                    selectedOptionView(radio_button1, 1)
                }
                R.id.radio_button2 -> {
                    selectedOptionView(radio_button2, 2)
                }
                R.id.radio_button3 -> {
                    selectedOptionView(radio_button3, 3)
                }
                R.id.radio_button4 -> {
                    selectedOptionView(radio_button4, 4)
                }
                R.id.btn_submit -> {
                    if (mSelectedOptionPosition == 0 && isRunning) {
// if no radio button selected and timer running when 'submit' is clicked
                        if (radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId == -1 && btn_submit.text == "SUBMIT") {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please select an answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            radio_group.clearCheck()
                            mCurrentPosition++
                        }
                        when {
                            mCurrentPosition <= mQuestionsList!!.size -> {
                                setQuestion()
                            }
                            else -> {
                                val intent = Intent(this, ResultsActivity::class.java)
                                intent.putExtra(ConstantsAssessment.TOTAL_CORRECT, mCorrectAnswers)
                                intent.putExtra(ConstantsAssessment.TOTAL_OPP, mQuestionsList!!.size)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        timer.cancel()
                        val questions2 = mQuestionsList?.get(mCurrentPosition - 1)
                        if (questions2!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionPosition) {
                            answerView(mSelectedOptionPosition, R.drawable.incorrect_option_border_bg)
                            if (questions2.dialogBox!=null) {
                                val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                dialogBuilder.setMessage(questions2.dialogBox!!)
                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                    .setNegativeButton("Close") { dialog, id -> dialog.cancel()
                                    }
                                val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
                                alert.show()
                            }
                        } else {
                            mCorrectAnswers++
                        }
                        answerView(questions2.correctAnswer, R.drawable.correct_option_border)
                        if (mCurrentPosition == mQuestionsList!!.size) {
                            btn_submit.text = "FINISH"
                        } else {
                            btn_submit.text = "NEXT QUESTION"
                            isRunning = true
                        }
                        mSelectedOptionPosition = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you're getting that specific behaviour with the code you've posted - it's acting like you're running your timer setup code again, so there are two running at once and that's why you're getting them fighting over what time should be displayed. At a guess, you're not cancelling the old one before you do `timer = blabla` and so it's just there running in the background, and you don't have a reference to it anymore.

Honestly if I were you I'd break that logic down into some separate functions, so you have the steps that your app needs to go through, from showing the question to validating the user's answer to moving on to the next. So you'd end up with something like this for your `onClick`:

```
fun reset() {
    clearTimer()
    clearRadioButtons()
    answerSelected = -1
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when(v?.id){
        R.id.radio_button1 -> answerSelected = 1
        R.id.radio_button2 -> answerSelected = 2
        R.id.radio_button3 -> answerSelected = 3
        R.id.radio_button4 -> answerSelected = 4
        R.id.btn_submit -> if (answerSelected == -1) showWarning() else submitAnswer(answerSelected)
    }
}

fun showWarning() {
    // show a warning toast, no need to do anything else
    // (including messing with the timer)
}

fun submitAnswer(answerNumber: Int) {
    // validate the input (e.g. answer between 1 and 4)
    // you might want to call showWarning() here instead, in response to validation failure
    recordAnswer()
    reset()
    // if you make setQuestion return false when there are no questions
    // left, you can check that and take action
    if (!setNextQuestion()) showResults()
}
```

There are lots of ways you could do it, but hopefully you get the idea. By breaking it down into smaller tasks (with good names so it reads like simple instructions) it's easier to reason about what's happening and go from step to step, taking whatever action is necessary.

By putting important actions like `clearTimer()` in their own function, you can see everywhere you take that action (by calling the function) and it's easier to tell if your basic flow is correct

Answer (score 0):

The issue has something to do with the timer being called in `setQuestion()` in the `when` statement below.

```
when {
   mCurrentPosition <= mQuestionsList!!.size -> {
      setQuestion()
   }
```

The issue was replicated by placing the timer in `onCreate` and calling `timer.start()` in the `when` statement. Removing `timer.start()` fixed the issue. The new code can be found below.

onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions_assessment)
        mQuestionsList = ConstantsAssessment.getQuestions2()
        setQuestion()
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_back.setOnClickListener() {
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
        timer = object: CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                val timeResult =
                    "${(millisUntilFinished/1000 / 60).toString().padStart(1, '0')}:" +
                            "${(millisUntilFinished/1000 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}"
                tv_timer.text = "$timeResult"
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
                isRunning = false
                btn_submit.callOnClick()
                timer.cancel()
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

Submit button

```
R.id.btn_submit -> {
                if (mSelectedOptionPosition == 0 && isRunning) {
                    if (radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId == -1 && btn_submit.text == "SUBMIT") {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please select an answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        radio_group.clearCheck()
                        mCurrentPosition++
                        timer.start()
                    }
                    when {
                        mCurrentPosition <= mQuestionsList!!.size -> {
                            setQuestion()
                        }
                        else -> {
                            val intent = Intent(this, ResultsActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra(ConstantsAssessment.TOTAL_CORRECT, mCorrectAnswers)
                            intent.putExtra(ConstantsAssessment.TOTAL_OPP, mQuestionsList!!.size)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                }
```